# The canonical way to use a QTimer in a separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtimer

I am tying to create a worker thread that will update a `QTWidget` at 1 second intervals (think of it as a digital clock or a progress bar updater might be a better analogy given the application).

My application is avionics specific that computes flight tracking info over a flight path and updates a map or some other QT widget regularly during the progress of the flight at 1 sec intervals (I suppose you could think of it as a sort of progress bar - where the progress bar could be replaced by a map or table widget in my case).   The thread will probably take about 10-20 seconds to compute the entire flight data - (however it will have its first results available almost immediately) - these results need to be sent at 1 second intervals to the GUI to update the position of an aircraft on a map.

There is a lot of confusion about the right and wrong way to incorporate a timer that updates a worker thread.   The best source of knowledge I found was a QtCon talk entitied [Multithreading with Qt - Giuseppe D’Angelo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcSsjxhazu0)  - it seems that the preferred method is to have a worker `QObject` that does not subclass a `QThread` and that has the timer running in its own event handler - but there is a lot of confusion about moving the worker thread to another thread that I don't understand very well and I am looking for some canonical advice on how to do this right.  Doing so in a Lambda would be ideal as I could keep the logic and threading relatively isolated which would be ideal.

I am looking to see if someone could point me in the direction of a similar example (especially if it uses modern Lambdas).  I am currently using QT 5.11.2.

My worker object (which contains the `QTimer` is as follows):

```
class SimulatedFlightWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit  SimulatedFlightWorker()
        : mpMMRFlightData{}
    {}
public slots:
    // worker thread slot that computes the mpMMRFlightData
    void importSimulatedFlight(
        const QString& fileName,
        const int aPlaybackSpeed);
    void updateGUI(int secondsElapsed);
signals:
    // every second during the flight we need to send a new MMR
    // record to the GUI - to display on a spreadsheet or google map
    void updateFlightData(const MMRTimedRecord& rMMRRecord);

    // this is effectively when the worker thread is done
    void flightCompleted();
private:
    QTimer mTimer;
    // the 
    std::unique_ptr<MMRFlightData> mpMMRFlightData;
};
```

This is the code where I setup the signals and slots (not working yet)

```
// Experimental worker model adapted from YouTube tutorial
// by Giuseppe di Angelo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgqT6SIeRn4
auto thread = new QThread;
auto worker = new SimulatedFlightWorker;


connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &SimulatedFlightWorker::importSimulatedFlight);
connect(worker, &SimulatedFlightWorker::flightCompleted, thread, &QThread::quit);
connect(thread, &QThread::finished, worker, &SimulatedFlightWorker::deleteLater);

worker->moveToThread(thread);
thread->start();
```

Comment: Creating a new thread for each timer tick maybe a bad idea performance-wise, it means a lot of context switching, so,  you can try something of those: 1. `QThreadPool` and `QRunnable`, 2. or `QtConcurrent::run()` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html,  use a `QFutureWatcher` to make the future really asynchronous and dispatches the result using signals and slots http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html.     The future way is the modern way, because it is somewhat like JavaScript's promises and Dart's futures, also note: the task will **NOT** be excuted **until** a thread is available.

Comment: @user9335240 there is just 1 QTimer that I would like to have running in the background in SimulatedFlightWorker that emits the timeout signal, something along the following lines connect(&mTimer, &QTimer::timeout, &this, &SimulatedFlightWorker::updateFlightData). Not really sure of this syntax but I am guessing that I would have to do this somewhere in my worker's constructor

Comment: Just try to use `QtConcurrent::run([=](){ /* Execute your lambda here */ });` This will return you a QFuture, `QFutureWatcher<int> watcher;
connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &myObject, SLOT(handleFinished()));

// Start the computation.
QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run([=](){ /* Execute your lambda here */ });
watcher.setFuture(future);`

Answer (score 2):

It’s really simple:

1. Your calculations are done in a QObject-derived class
2. Updates are issued via a signal in that object.
3. Calculations are done in small chunks that take 10-20ms.
4. The calcualtions are triggered from a zero-duration timer – it’s not a timer, but a way of detecting event loop idle state in a thread.
5. The updates are triggered from a 1-second timer.

This class can be run on any thread — it will even work on the GUI thread, but will make it a bit less responsive (but not at all unresponsive).

You’d normally instantiate the class, start computations, and move it to a dedicated thread.

Comment: @KuberOber thanks for the rules, the place I am having a little trouble is how to correctly initialize the timer in the QObject-derived class, do I embed it as a member of the class and how to I initialize it correctly.  If you had a little example showing how to add this to a simple GUI that would be great.

Comment: Add a member of type `QTimer`. It must be owned by the class. No need to dynamically allocate it. E.g., in the body of the class: `QTimer m_updateTimer{this};`

Comment: any chance you could put tiny example together that shows how I can use this - I'm a relative QT newbie and am still having a problem with setting up the correct signals/slots syntax for this to work correctly.  In my main window class for ex, do I need have a dedicated Qthread member where I should move the thread to (I don't want to interfere with the GUI thread whatsoever).  I would like to start the worker in an on_button_xxx slot.

Comment: Are you also a C++ newbie? That makes a big difference. There’s little that’s Qt specific in all of this. A `QThread` is a nullable thread handle (null when thread is stopped), you’d use it the way you use any other resource handle.

Comment: The newbie comment wasn't helpful in answering this question.  That being said, I made some progress with a self contained example.  I have 1 problem, my regular 1sec emit updates are not getting forwarded to the GUI thread.  bool connected = connect(&mWorkerThread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::doWork);
    //connected = connect(worker, &Worker::progressUpdate, [=](const MMRTimedRecord&) {}); // this works (newline)
    connected = connect(worker, &Worker::progressUpdate, this, &mainwindow::updateSimulatedFlight, Qt::QueuedConnection);

Comment: I’m trying to understand whether you are a C++ newbie or not. That’s all, as that will dictate the level of detail needed when discussing it. Are you fairly familiar with C++11 & 14?

Comment: I'm pretty up with the latest c++17 - actually.  Feet free to flood me with template meta snippets - QT takes a different (in my opinion impuree) approach to memory managementbugbtbis is not really the place for that discussion